# Maximum number of nodes in a balanced binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, nodes, binary-search-tree

Could anyone suggest a recursive formula for finding the maximum number of nodes in a binary search tree? I know the generic formula for a tree with depth n is 2^(n+1)-1, but the recursive part is confusing me.

Comment: Did you try to google this?

Comment: I did but couldn't find a clear answer.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by maximum number of nodes? You just want to find/traverse all the nodes, yes?

Comment: I would like a formula that finds the maximum number of nodes possible in a balanced binary tree. It would use the depth, n, and put it into the formula - (2^(n+1))-1  i.e. If the depth is 4 then the maximum number of nodes possible in that tree would be 31. I am thinking if the method is called maxNodes(), then maxNodes(null) would return zero, maxNodes(leaf x) would return 1, but for maxNodes(root LxR) I am unsure what it would return using recursion. (to clarify, root LxR is a node x with a left and right subtree.)

Answer (score 2):

Think I've got it now:

B(n) = (2^n) + B(n-1) , n=depth of tree

Comment: If anyone has any ideas on how to find the minimum number of nodes possible in a tree with depth n using recursion, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jmoerdyk This _is_ an answer to the question the OP asked.